# Is there a way to access a private .zip S3 object with a django app's .ebextension config file deployed on elastic beanstalk

Tags: python-3.x, django, oracle, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

We have a django app deployed on elastic beanstalk, and added a feature that accesses an oracle DB. cx-Oracle requires the Oracle client library (instant client), and we would like to have the .zip for the library available as a private object in our S3 bucket, public object is not an option. We want to avoid depending on an Oracle link with wget. I am struggling to develop a .config file in the .ebextensions directory that will install the .zip S3 any time it is deployed. How can was set-up the config to install on deployment?

os: Amazon Linux AMI 1

Answer (score 0):

Sure that is a common practice to get your private files from s3.
You need to have IAM permission (on EB cluster) to access your s3 bucket and download files.
The config in .ebextensions can look something like this:

```
 container_commands:
  install:
    command: |
      #!/bin/bash -xe
        aws s3 cp s3:/bucket-name/your-file local-filename
```

Just like a friendly suggestion, EB is ok to start with but if your app will go to production you will run on some problems (like cannot enforce some ports to not be opened etc) and maybe there are some better options for you to host your app (ECS, EKS etc)